# How to compare hazard ratios of different levels in Cox regression from R output?

Tags: r, regression, cox-regression, hazard

I've run a *Cox regression model* with *a categorical predictor* and I'm not sure whether I can compare the different levels to each other, or just to the reference category?

For example, in the lung dataset:

```
lung$ph.ecog=factor(lung$ph.ecog)
fit1=coxph(Surv(lung$time, lung$status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)
```

I know you'd never set *ph.ecog* as a factor, its just demonstrative. The output of this model is (the reference is 0):

```
           coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)    
ph.ecog1 0.3688    1.4461   0.1987 1.857   0.0634 .  
ph.ecog2 0.9164    2.5002   0.2245 4.081 4.48e-05 ***
ph.ecog3 2.2080    9.0973   1.0258 2.152   0.0314 *
```

So, I know that `ph.ecog=1` has a hazard ratio of `1.44` which means it is *1.4* times more likely than `ph.ecog=0`, and a level of *2* is *2.5* times more likely than `0`, but can I say that `ph.ecog` 2 is *1.728926* (=2.5002/1.4461) more likely than ph.ecog=1?

Is this also true for other regression models, such as odds ratios?

Many thanks

Comment: You are correct that hazard ratio for ecog 2 vs ecog 1 is 1.728926. For odds ratio, this method is also applicable.